# Validate model with sqlalchemy AsyncSession

Tags: asynchronous, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi, pydantic

I have a FastAPI server and a PostgresSQL database integrated using sqlalchemy. This is the dependency to get the database (I'm following [sqlalchemy async best practicies](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#asyncio-orm-avoid-lazyloads)):

```py
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, AsyncAttrs
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from typing import AsyncGenerator
from typing import Generator
from urllib.parse import quote

# Setting the constant DATABASE_URL...

engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True)

# Configure async SessionLocal class
# AsyncSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession)
AsyncSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)

class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

async def get_db() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with AsyncSessionLocal() as db:
        yield db
```

This is my crud operation

```py
async def create_user(db: AsyncSession, user: UserSchema) -> User:
    hashed_password = pwd_context.hash(user.password)
    db_user = User(username=user.username, email=user.email, phone_number=user.phone_number, hashed_password=hashed_password)
    db.add(db_user)
    try:
        await db.commit()
        await db.refresh(db_user)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        await db.rollback()
        if "unique constraint" in str(e.orig).lower():
            raise UserExistsException("User with given email or username already exists.")
        else:
            raise
    return db_user
```

And this is my route

```py
from ..crud.users import create_user as crud_create_user
# Other imports...

@router.post("/users/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_user(user: UserSchema, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    """
    Create a new user
    """
    try:
        user = await crud_create_user(db=db, user=user)
        print(f"{user = }")
        print(f"{user.__dict__ = }")
        print("This works")
        
        # This is the problem, I can't extract attributes
        user = UserResponseSchema.model_validate(user)

        return user
    except (ValueError, UserExistsException) as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))
```

I get a 400 error containing this error:

```
2 validation errors for UserResponseSchema\ncustom_apps\n  Error extracting attribute: MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s) [type=get_attribute_error, input_value=<chatbot_deployment_platf...t at 0x0000027ABB8F9E10>, input_type=User]\n    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/get_attribute_error\npayment_info\n  Error extracting attribute: MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s) [type=get_attribute_error, input_value=<chatbot_deployment_platf...t at 0x0000027ABB8F9E10>, input_type=User]\n    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/get_attribute_error
```

If you follow the links you get to the [sqlalchemy async best practicies](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#asyncio-orm-avoid-lazyloads) and if I use `@router.post("/users/", response_model=UserResponseSchema, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)` and remove the `user = UserResponseSchema.model_validate(user)` line I get the same result (but with 500 error in this case).

I'm new to sqlalchemy, but what I want to achieve is to solve this error while maintaining my code structure and without changing the type of loading, that is lazy loading at the moment:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs

class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class UserRole(enum.Enum):
    USER = "user"
    ADMIN = "admin"

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    phone_number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    hashed_password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    role: Mapped[UserRole] = mapped_column(Enum(UserRole, name='role'), default=UserRole.USER)
    is_email_verified: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_phone_verified: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    
    custom_apps: Mapped["CustomApp"] = relationship("CustomApp", back_populates='owner')
    payment_info: Mapped["PaymentInfo"] = relationship("PaymentInfo", back_populates='user')
    support_tickets: Mapped["SupportTicket"] = relationship("SupportTicket", back_populates='user')
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The error is caused by a relationship being accessed that wasn't loaded when you made the query; because you're using the async support, SQLAlchemy can't go out and fetch it for you when needed since it happens internally (and not necessarily in an async context). Add proper joins to load the relationships when querying the data, or remove the relationships from your Pydantic model. So you'll have to at least take special care for async loading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77734769/137650 - Pydantic does not do this automagically for you, as it's only concerned with it being an attribute.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76539549/pydantic-with-asyncattrs-sqlalchemy - but you're generally just doing eager loading when you load all the attributes afterwards, so in that case it's better to explicitly load them with the original query instead of making N queries later.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh. So, I see I have two options (correct?):
- Set eager loading as `lazy` argument in the relationship (I think I would go for "selectinload", it's the one I've seen used the most)
- "Manual" loading: Instead of using .model_validate, I manually use await statements to load the attributes of `user`, I guess using session's `AsyncAttrs.awaitable_attrs` (not sure how tho)
In both cases I don't understand the meaning of lazy loading when using async, if it doesn't load attributes when I use them, is it the same of `noload`? Is lazy loading unusable with async?

Comment: lazy loading means that the attributes gets loaded from the database when they're used; which means that they need to be loaded in a async context. This is done by using something like the `@property` decorator, which exposes a function as a property - so the function gets called when the property is accessed. However, this isn't visible to the calling code, so the calling code won't `await` that part, and thus it doesn't work the sqlalchemy expects to be called in a async context with await (the greenlet error). If you already know you are going to access the properties, use a strategy

Comment: already when querying. And yes, lazy loading is hard to get correct when using async (which is why it isn't solved automagically by SQLAlchemy for you). You have to `await` the property access (which really is a async function behind the scenes with you use `AsyncAttrs`) as shown in the linked answer from another question about the same. The quickest solution: adjust your relationship loading strategy if suitable (i.e. if you use that relationship all the time) or do a joinedload or similar when querying if you only need it for specific cases (and don't try to access it afterwards).

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. I will use eager loading in my relationship, because I do not have special requirements for any endpoint at this moment. This is an answer for me :)